# Pylons uploads url 404 on nginx

Tags: routes, nginx, pylons

I have deployed my pylons app on the server~

I use nginx end flup, here are the confs
cat vps.ini

```
[server:main]

 use = egg.Flup#fcgi_thread
 host = 0.0.0.0
 port = 5000
 [app:main]
 ...
 permanent_store = %(here)s/data/uploads
```

cat /etc/nginx/site-enabled/pylons

```
server{ listen 80;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_index index;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

cat Cksite/cksite/config/routing.py

```
map.connect('upload/*url')
```

link

```
cd Cksite/cksite/public/ 
ln -s ../../data/uploads .uploads
```

but when I upload a image to the server and visit the url I got a 404 Not Found page.

```
http://znetor.tk/uploads/22494C1F3AA5FBCDC07F28FF821DC6C1.jpg
```

all things works well on my laptop with paster server development.ini~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for this is will be to put your upload directory directly on the public folder of your project

This way you won't get into folder permission issues, it's way better than symlinking in my own opinion